# i want to convert UIImageView to UIImage or in PDF also, is it possible??

Tags: ios5

i have taken an UIImageView on top of it taken some labels now i want to convert this UIImageView to UIImage or in PDF also, is it possible??

Answer (score 0):

By your question , it seems you want to take a screenshot of your view and save it as an image or pdf.
You can take Screenshot of view and save it in photo Gallery using following code.

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size);
[self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *screenShotimage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(screenShotimage, nil, nil, nil);
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: // Retrieves the document directories from the iOS device
    NSArray* documentDirectories = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask,YES);
    
    NSString* documentDirectory = [documentDirectories objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString* documentDirectoryFilename = [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.pdf"];
    
    // instructs the mutable data object to write its context to a file on disk
    [pdfData writeToFile:documentDirectoryFilename atomically:YES];